# Angular Compare Password Directive

Tags: angularjs

I have this form that has a password filed and a confirmPassword field. I want to compare the password field against the confirmPassword field. I'm having a little of a problem doing so, because I have an ng-show that should only display a "Passwords Do Not Match" error when the password don't match but at the moment the messages always shows.

```
    <label class="control-label">Password *
  <div class="row m-b-15">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="control-label">Re-enter Password *</label>
  <div class="row m-b-15">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Re-enter Password" name="confirmPassword" required="" ng-model="user.confirmPassword" ka-compare-to="user.password" class="form-control"/>
      <div ng-show="signUpForm.confirmPassword.$error" class="form-group has-error">
        <label class="control-label">Passwords Do Not Match</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>

.directive('kaCompareTo', function(){

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            otherModelValue: '=kaCompareTo'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel){

            ngModel.$validators.kaCompareTo = function(modelValue){

                return modelValue === scope.otherModelValue;
            };

            scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {

                ngModel.$validate();
            });

        }

    }

})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check for `$submitted` also in ng-show. Might also look into how `ng-messages` works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make it work you should change ng-show condition from `signUpForm.confirmPassword.$error` to `signUpForm.confirmPassword.$error.kaCompareTo`

To achieve same behaviour, you can use AngularJS "ng-pattern" attribute instead of creating a custom directive. IMHO it is even better solution, because it returns error only if "confirmPassword" is not empty:

```
<input 
type="text" 
placeholder="Re-enter Password" 
name="confirmPassword" 
required="" 
ng-pattern="user.password" 
ng-model="user.confirmPassword" 
class="form-control"/>
<div 
ng-show="signUpForm.confirmPassword.$error.pattern" 
class="form-group has-error">
    <label class="control-label">Passwords Do Not Match</label>
</div>
```